# A four digit year could not be found Data missing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

I'm trying to seed using factories in Laravel 5.2

My code dies in the User factory:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
$countries = Countries::all()->pluck('id')->toArray();

return [
    'name' => $faker->name,
    'email' => $faker->email,
    'password' => bcrypt(str_random(10)),
    'grade_id' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 5),
    'country_id' => $faker->randomElement($countries),
    'city' => $faker->city,
    'latitude' => $faker->latitude,
    'longitude' => $faker->longitude,
    'role_id' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 3),
    'verified' => true,
    'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    'provider' => '',
    'provider_id' => str_random(5)

];
});
```

Giving me this error:

```
A four digit year could not be found   Data missing
```

I found the cause, but don't know how to fix it.

When I call the factory, I call it like that:

```
    factory(User::class)->create(['role_id',2]);
```

If I call it like that:

```
    factory(User::class)->create();
```

I get no more error.
But I really need to seed different kind of users...

Any idea???

Comment: have you tried using key value array in create like: `factory(User::class)->create(['role_id' => 2]);`

Comment: OMG So Stupid! Please put it as answer!

Comment: I have the same issue, it took me around 2 minutes to notice the `=>` instead of `,` in the array parameter of `create`.

Comment: You make my day @anpel

Comment: Thanks. I made the same typo. That's a terrible error message isn't it? Not at all descriptive of the actual problem.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

have you tried using key value array in the `create` method:

`factory(User::class)->create(['role_id' => 2]);`

Comment: Thank you for this.
I totally forgot that this was `Associative Array`

Comment: I run into this problem every time using carbon in a model factory and trying to override factory attributes in the create method ha ha. This post definitely helps every time.

Answer (score 4):

I might be late to the party, I was having the same problem and it turns out its because I provided a key without a value in the array returned.

get rid of `'provider' => ''`.

As to the cause of the problem i really don't know but it has something to do with Carbon

Comment: for me it was the date format provided through `protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:sO';` which did not match the column's format because of a borked migration. carbon did not like that and threw a "data missing" error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when using mass assignment and it turned I had forgotten to wrap my array of inputs in the request helper function

That is I had
Model::create([form inputs]);

Instead of
Model::create(request([form inputs]);

Just incase someone comes across it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encounter the same problem, lately I found out that the only problem is **I put an invalid value to the timestamp column type**.

In my case I have column `email_verified_at [timestamp]`. I miss understood I put a string like `company@example.com` instead of *date values*, it should be `now()`.